Problems adding an animated HTML canvas background to webpage
I am trying to add the following animation to my webpage background link to the background, the problem i'm facing is that the background loads on top of all the content of my webpage, as to by becoming the first top layer hiding all my content beneath it and z-index is not working either? Please advise a solution
i tried z-index and positioning of the canvas and the container divs


function hideOtherImages(clickedImage) {
  var images = document.getElementsByClassName("gallery-image");
  var h5s = document.getElementsByTagName("h5");

  for (var i = 0; i < images.length; i++) {
    if (images[i] !== clickedImage) {
      images[i].style.display = "none";
      h5s[i].style.display = "none"; // Hide the h5 element corresponding to the image
    }
  }
}
<canvas id="canvas">
  <h1>Explore what your star sign means and has for you!</h1>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="one">
      <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?aries" alt="" class="gallery-image" onclick="hideOtherImages(this)" ><h5>March 21 – April 19</h5></figure>


      <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?taurus" alt="" class="gallery-image" onclick="hideOtherImages(this)" ><h5>April 20 – May 20</h5></figure>
      <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?gemini" alt="" class="gallery-image" onclick="hideOtherImages(this)"><h5>May 21 – June 20</h5></figure>
      <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?cancer" alt="" class="gallery-image" onclick="hideOtherImages(this)"><h5>June 21 – July 22</h5></figure>
      <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?leo" alt="" class="gallery-image" onclick="hideOtherImages(this)"><h5>July 23 – August 22</h5></figure>
      <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?virgo" alt="" class="gallery-image" onclick="hideOtherImages(this)"><h5>August 23 – September 22</h5></figure>
    </div>
    <div class="two" >
      <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?libra" alt="" class="gallery-image" onclick="hideOtherImages(this)"><h5>September 23 – October 22</h5></figure>
      <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?scorpio" alt="" class="gallery-image" onclick="hideOtherImages(this)"><h5>October 23 – November 21</h5></figure>
      <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?sagittarius" alt="" class="gallery-image" onclick="hideOtherImages(this)"><h5>November 22 – December 21</h5></figure>
      <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?capricorn" alt="" class="gallery-image" onclick="hideOtherImages(this)"><h5>December 22 – January 19</h5></figure>
      <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?aquarius" alt="" class="gallery-image" onclick="hideOtherImages(this)"><h5>January 20 – February 18</h5></figure>
      <figure><img src="https://picsum.photos/100/100?pisces" alt="" class="gallery-image" onclick="hideOtherImages(this)"><h5>February 19 – March 20</h5></figure>
    </div>
  </div>
</canvas>




Couple of things need changing.
The text should not be within the canvas element but come after it in the DOM.
The canvas needs to be positioned either absolute or fixed, depending on what you want when scrolling happens, so it doesn’t stop the text starting at the top.

You'll need z-index: 99999; and position: fixed; to make elements appear. Here's a clean, good-looking, and minimal example.


const rand = function(min, max) {
  return Math.random() * (max - min) + min;
}

let canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
let ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

window.addEventListener('resize', function() {
  canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
  canvas.height = window.innerHeight;
  ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
  ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';
});
let backgroundColors = ['#000', '#000'];
let colors = [
  ['#002aff', "#009ff2"],
  ['#0054ff', '#27e49b'],
  ['#202bc5', '#873dcc']
];
let count = 70;
let blur = [12, 70];
let radius = [1, 120];

ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.globalCompositeOperation = 'lighter';

let grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(0, canvas.height, canvas.width, 0);
grd.addColorStop(0, backgroundColors[0]);
grd.addColorStop(1, backgroundColors[1]);
ctx.fillStyle = grd;
ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);

let items = [];

while (count--) {
  let thisRadius = rand(radius[0], radius[1]);
  let thisBlur = rand(blur[0], blur[1]);
  let x = rand(-100, canvas.width + 100);
  let y = rand(-100, canvas.height + 100);
  let colorIndex = Math.floor(rand(0, 299) / 100);
  let colorOne = colors[colorIndex][0];
  let colorTwo = colors[colorIndex][1];

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.filter = `blur(${thisBlur}px)`;
  let grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(x - thisRadius / 2, y - thisRadius / 2, x + thisRadius, y + thisRadius);

  grd.addColorStop(0, colorOne);
  grd.addColorStop(1, colorTwo);
  ctx.fillStyle = grd;
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.arc(x, y, thisRadius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();

  let directionX = Math.round(rand(-99, 99) / 100);
  let directionY = Math.round(rand(-99, 99) / 100);

  items.push({
    x: x,
    y: y,
    blur: thisBlur,
    radius: thisRadius,
    initialXDirection: directionX,
    initialYDirection: directionY,
    initialBlurDirection: directionX,
    colorOne: colorOne,
    colorTwo: colorTwo,
    gradient: [x - thisRadius / 2, y - thisRadius / 2, x + thisRadius, y + thisRadius],
  });
}


function changeCanvas(timestamp) {
  ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
  let adjX = 2;
  let adjY = 2;
  let adjBlur = 1;
  items.forEach(function(item) {

    if (item.x + (item.initialXDirection * adjX) >= canvas.width && item.initialXDirection !== 0 || item.x + (item.initialXDirection * adjX) <= 0 && item.initialXDirection !== 0) {
      item.initialXDirection = item.initialXDirection * -1;
    }
    if (item.y + (item.initialYDirection * adjY) >= canvas.height && item.initialYDirection !== 0 || item.y + (item.initialYDirection * adjY) <= 0 && item.initialYDirection !== 0) {
      item.initialYDirection = item.initialYDirection * -1;
    }

    if (item.blur + (item.initialBlurDirection * adjBlur) >= radius[1] && item.initialBlurDirection !== 0 || item.blur + (item.initialBlurDirection * adjBlur) <= radius[0] && item.initialBlurDirection !== 0) {
      item.initialBlurDirection *= -1;
    }

    item.x += (item.initialXDirection * adjX);
    item.y += (item.initialYDirection * adjY);
    item.blur += (item.initialBlurDirection * adjBlur);
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.filter = `blur(${item.blur}px)`;
    let grd = ctx.createLinearGradient(item.gradient[0], item.gradient[1], item.gradient[2], item.gradient[3]);
    grd.addColorStop(0, item.colorOne);
    grd.addColorStop(1, item.colorTwo);
    ctx.fillStyle = grd;
    ctx.arc(item.x, item.y, item.radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.fill();
    ctx.closePath();

  });
  window.requestAnimationFrame(changeCanvas);

}

window.requestAnimationFrame(changeCanvas);
body {
  font-family: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, 'Segoe UI', Roboto, Oxygen, Ubuntu, Cantarell, 'Open Sans', 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  padding: 0;
  background: black;
  margin: 0;
}

canvas {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#hello-text {
  z-index: 99999;
  position: fixed;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  color: white;
  font-size: 72px;
}
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
<h1 id="hello-text">Hello</h1>




Do you want the text to be fixed?
